# Bash script for converting IP Addr string to Hexadecimal format

Tags: bash

`IP_ADDR=192.168.1.128`

printf '%02X' ${IP_ADDR//./ }; echo

Can some one explain how this simple oneliner converts IP_ADDR to hexadecimal format? I am banging my head trying to find some documentation about this behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

```
$ IP_ADDR=192.168.1.128
$ echo ${IP_ADDR//./ }
192 168 1 128
$ printf '%02X' 192 168 1 128 ; echo
C0A80180
```

Comment: @Ignacio Is there reverse function for this?

Comment: @GaneshSatpute this will reverse it:

`printf '%d.%d.%d.%d\n' \`echo 4A3EBA33 | sed -r 's/(..)/0x\1 /g'\``

Every two digits are converted to "0xN ", where N is the two digits. Then printf converts each hex value to a decimal number and puts a '.' in between them.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `gethostip` (from syslinux-utils on Debian/Ubuntu):

```
$ gethostip -x 192.168.1.128
C0A80180
```